# Prove that $\left\|f_n(x)-g_n(x)\right\|^2 = \|f_n(x)\|^2+ \|g_n(x) \|^2-2\operatorname{Re}\int_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)\overline{g_m(x)} dx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$, $\{g_n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ be two sequence of square-integrable functions: $f_n, g_n\in L^2(\mathbb R)$. Prove that
$$\left\|f_n(x)-g_n(x)\right\|^2_{L^2(\mathbb R)} = \left\|f_n(x)\right\|^2_{L^2(\mathbb R)} + \left\|g_n(x)  \right\|^2_{L^2(\mathbb R)}-2\operatorname{Re}\int_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)\overline{g_m(x)} dx$$
I can not understand the presence, in the formula, of the operator $\operatorname{Re}$. Why?

Comment: Use the definition of the norm: $\|f-g\|=\sqrt{\langle f-g,f-g\rangle}$ in the $L^2$-space, the definition of the inner product, and two properties of complex numbers: $2Re z=z+\overline z$ and $\overline{zw}=\overline {z}\cdot\overline{w}$

Comment: @Svetoslav. Oh, thanks!